# Copy data from different oracle to Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

What is the best way to copy data from Oracle to Amazon DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the [AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.html).

It can read from Oracle and write to DynamoDB.